# How to have Gitlab display a Markdown document as source?

Tags: markdown

For our current project, we have Markdown source files which aren't acting as project documentation (such as a `README.md`) but rather as the source of the project itself.

It would be very helpful if I could instruct Gitlab that these files are not to be rendered into HTML but displayed as raw source files.  The source files are intended to be processed by pandoc, so a lot of the formatting gets clumsily misinterpreted by Gitlab.

Is there a setting to turn rendering off for specific files?

Comment: BTW, it'd be nice to have a tag for gitlab.  Can someone with the rep create one?

Comment: There is no tag for gitlab because it is a web app and questions regarding web apps belong on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/  Your question should be moved there shortly.

Comment: heavyd, GitLab can be run as a web app on GitLab Cloud but most people use it on-premises as installable software, so I think and hope a tag can be created.

Comment: I've opened a [bug report / feature request for this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13962) as I need the same feature myself. Please subscribe there for updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to turn off rendering for specific files but every file does have the raw button to see it without markup.